# How can I take all value in screen?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have an employee table I filtered from Location with a combobox in WPF MVVM.
like that:

in xaml:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"   ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LocationFilterCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
```

In ViewModel:

```
  Locations = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            { "All","A","B"};
```

and in LocationFilterCommand

```
 #region LocationFilterCommand

        private DelegateCommand _locationFilterCommand;
        public DelegateCommand LocationFilterCommand
        {
            get { return _locationFilterCommand ?? (_locationFilterCommand = new DelegateCommand(CanLocationFilter, LocationFilter)); }
        }

        private bool CanLocationFilter()
        {


            return true;
        }
        private void LocationFilter()
        {
            ParticularEntries = ParticularEntries.Where(p =>p.Region.Location==_selectedLocation);
           }
```

I dont have problem with  when I select A location or when I select B location they comes to screen.But I dont know how to take all values together with "All" item in combobox?
Hint:All is not a location type.All need all locations employee together come to screen.But I dont know how to this filter ?
thank you for all your helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use combobox with wpf mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60781745/how-can-i-use-combobox-with-wpf-mvvm)

Comment: for A location and for B location it's true.But an extra all item in combobox it's not work actually